# WebRTC with Agora.io: SwitchCamera?

Tags: agora.io

I'm building a web app using Agora.io. I'd like to be able to switch from the front-facing to the rear-facing camera on a client's smartphone. I've seen agora docs for `switchCamera`. I've tried the following:

```
switchCamera();
myAgoraClient.switchCamera();
localStream.switchCamera();
```

All of them throw a `no such function` error.

What is the correct way to switch the camera in agora.io for web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with *[switchDevice](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#switchdevice)* method in [2.5 SDK](http://download.agora.io/sdk/release/Agora_Web_SDK_v2_5_0_FULL.zip)

> switchDevice(type: string, deviceId: string, onSuccess: function,
>   onFailure: function): void

For example;

```
localStream.switchDevice("video", "<deviceid>", console.log,console.log)
```

Should do the work. I was trying same thing but examples contains old 2.4 js sdk, you need to specifically download ^2.5

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the latest version of Agora Web SDK have these methods out of box.

However, you can create a camera list through:

```
AgoraRTC.getDevices(function(devices){
  cameras = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput');
});
```

Then give switchCamera an implementation:

```
function switchCamera(){
    cameraIndex = (++cameraIndex) % cameras.length;
}
```

Use `cameras[cameraIndex].deviceId` as `cameraId` to create a new local video stream and publish it out.

Comment: Agora tech support emailed me to say that a built-in function to handle camera switching is on the way, most likely by the end of the month.

Comment: @VikR, any update after almost  2 years?

Comment: Yes, Agora has come a long way since then. See their docs at https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/switchdevice_web